# Magento onestepcheckout on mobile template wont show

Tags: php, magento, mobile, onestepcheckout

In the mobile template of my magento shop, it doesnt happen anything if I go to checkout in the cart. The checkout page is empty. I add an item into the cart and go to the cart page. Then i press continue to checkout and this comes:https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypA8i.png

Can you please help me? I have no idea why this wont work.

Comment: Have you found an answer? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your template probably hardcodes the checkout button url and you get directed to wonderland, worth to check the actual link behind the checkout button.